# not able to access the image in a row which is added using addrow button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code, that will append the table row with one image in last column whenever user clicks on add row button. But i would like to access the image (delete) to delete the row. But i am not able to do, Please help me. Below is my code

```js
$(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "#insptable .delete", function() { 
        alert("i am"); 
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

add row

```js
$(document).on("click", "#addrow", function (e) {
 $('#insptable tbody').append('<tr><td><input type="text" list="inppara" id="inpparameter" ><datalist id="inppara"><option value="TypeRating">TypeRating</option><option value="Operation Check">Operation Check</option><option value="Ext.Apperance">Ext.Apperance</option><option value="Verify TC">Verify TC</option><option value="Material">Material</option><option value="Dimension Check">Dimension Check</option><option value="Threads Check">Threads Check</option><option value="Visual Check">Visual Check</option><option value="Specification">Specification</option><option value="Batch no">Batch no</option><option value="Mfg.Date">Mfg.Date</option><option value="Exp.Date">Exp.Date</option></datalist><td><input type="text" list="inpsepci" id="inpspec" ><datalist id="inpsepci"><option value="AsperPO">AsperPO</option><option value="Damage">Damage</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="Stainless Steel">Stainless Steel</option><option value="Gaues">Gaues</option><option value="Mild Steel">Mild Steel</option><option value="As per Drawing">As per Drawing</option><option value="Cast Iron">Cast Iron</option><option value="Copper">Copper</option><option value="Aluminium">Aluminium</option><option value="Brass">Brass</option><option value="Spring Steel">Spring Steel</option><option value="Tool Steel">Tool Steel</option><option value="Nylon">Nylon</option><option value="CRGO">CRGO</option><option value="EN1">EN1</option><option value="EN2">EN2</option></datalist></td><td><input type="text" list="act1" id="inpact10" class="tb3"><datalist id="act1"><option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist></td><td><input type="text" list="act2" id="inpact20" class="tb3"><datalist id="act2"><option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist></td><td><input type="text" list="act3" id="inpact30" class="tb3"><datalist id="act3"><option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist></td><td><input type="text" list="act4" id="inpact40" class="tb3"><datalist id="act4"><option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist></td><td><input type="text" list="act5" id="inpact50" class="tb3"><datalist id="act5"><option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist></td></td><td><img src="delete.gif" height="42" width="42" alt="idata" class="del"></td></tr>');
 
});
```

My table has below structure.
1. If i have data in database table, then i will load it dynamically and append delete icon in last column (so that user can delete if they dont want).
In this way i could access the image and delete the row using above mentined $("body").code.
2. If i dont have any data database for a given input, then i am displaying default row in table with last column with delete image. below is the append code.

```js
else {
  // add default row and allow user to give input
  alert("No matched criteria for selected item! Please create new");
  var $tbl = $("#insptable");
  $tbody = $tbl.find('tbody');
  $tbl.find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
  $('#insptable tbody').append('<tr><td><input type="text" list="inppara" id="inpparameter" ><datalist id="inppara"><option value="TypeRating">TypeRating</option><option value="Operation Check">Operation Check</option><option value="Ext.Apperance">Ext.Apperance</option><option value="Verify TC">Verify TC</option><option value="Material">Material</option><option value="Dimension Check">Dimension Check</option><option value="Threads Check">Threads Check</option><option value="Visual Check">Visual Check</option><option value="Specification">Specification</option><option value="Batch no">Batch no</option><option value="Mfg.Date">Mfg.Date</option><option value="Exp.Date">Exp.Date</option></datalist><td><input type="text" list="inpsepci" id="inpspec" ><datalist id="inpsepci"><option value="AsperPO">AsperPO</option><option value="Damage">Damage</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="Stainless Steel">Stainless Steel</option><option value="Gaues">Gaues</option><option value="Mild Steel">Mild Steel</option><option value="As per Drawing">As per Drawing</option><option value="Cast Iron">Cast Iron</option><option value="Copper">Copper</option><option value="Aluminium">Aluminium</option><option value="Brass">Brass</option><option value="Spring Steel">Spring Steel</option><option value="Tool Steel">Tool Steel</option><option value="Nylon">Nylon</option><option value="CRGO">CRGO</option><option value="EN1">EN1</option><option value="EN2">EN2</option></datalist></td><td><input type="text" list="act1" id="inpact10" class="tb3"><datalist id="act1"><option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist></td><td><input type="text" list="act2" id="inpact20" class="tb3"><datalist id="act2"><option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist></td><td><input type="text" list="act3" id="inpact30" class="tb3"><datalist id="act3"><option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist></td><td><input type="text" list="act4" id="inpact40" class="tb3"><datalist id="act4"><option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist></td><td><input type="text" list="act5" id="inpact50" class="tb3"><datalist id="act5"><option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist></td></td><td><img src="delete.gif" height="42" width="42" alt="idata" class="del"></td></tr>');
  $('.rem').show();
  $("#addrow").show();
}
```

so in this case, i am not able to access last delete image.

And also i am not able to access the same if my row added using add row button as mentioned already.

Comment: — Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Rayon. Please see my edited post.

Comment: Oh boy. I want my 5 minutes back! Do you even double check your code? I mean ever? In the append section you are givin `del` as the class name but then you are tryin to call it in your function as `delete`. Puh-lease!

Comment: @Ryan.Hunt: Oops!!!! blind mistake which consumed my time :( anyhow thanks a lot!!!!